# Weird error message for denied fb app item submission

Tags: facebook, api, web-applications

This is not for Facebook api authentication but for item permission management for the app.

I'm currently in the process of resubmitting my application for item approval. One of the items I previously submitted and was rejected was the `read_friendlists` item. Here's the weird part..

This is the error message that I got from the submission:

**it looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the read_friendlists permission in the last 30 days**

I don't understand what the message means.  Im in the process of getting this permission.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to explicitly request those Fields in the request parameter when asking Friend's data.

for example

```
private void makeMyFriendsRequest(final Session session) {

    Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                for (GraphUser user : users) {
                    System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
                    System.out.println(users.get(i).getId());
                    GraphLocation loc = users.get(i).getLocation();
                    System.out.println(loc != null ? loc.getCity() : "loc not available");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

// here add fields explicitly

```
Bundle bundle = request.getParameters();
bundle.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,birthday,location");
request.executeAsync();
```

I hope this will help.